# Displaying "show X more" (starred) in chat is a tease?

Tags: bug, chat, chat-stars

In chat, when clicking on the "show X more" link to show more recently starred messages, the new entries are added beyond the exiting view and are tucked away under the footer.

The scrollbar is useless in this case since it only scrolls the chat section. So how do I get at the messages?

(See also: [Starred messages in chat room](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113595/starred-messages-in-chat-room). Possibly the same issue but hard to tell based on the information provided)

I can get at the hidden content by enlarging the browser window or zooming out, but considering the number of items initially shown is already scaled based on the available space, I'd expect the "show more" link to indeed show more items irrespective of my screen resolution.

Is this a bug, or am I missing something obvious?

---

[image: before clicky, no see messages]

[image: after clicky, still no see messages]

Comment: Arrange your monitor(s) vertically like me.  I can fit lots of starred messages :P

Comment: Please post a *full* (at least full-height) screenshot

Comment: @balpha Full-height screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/bbOJC.png

Comment: BTW, browser = FF8.0. Repro on FF3.6.20 and IE8.

Comment: For comparison purposes, here are screenshots of the same chat on my 1680x1050 monitor in [portrait orientation](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1BU91.png) and [landscape orientation](http://i.stack.imgur.com/oj7uK.png) @balpha

Comment: @PopularDemand - What's the point?  You don't have any option to show more messages.  [Here's my 1920x1200 monitor in portrait orientation](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BuFbP.png) which can fit about three times as many starred messages as are displayed.  I don't see how that helps at all, except to emphasize the point that the number of displayed (and requested) starred messages is independent of the browser height.  Perhaps there should be a feature request to make the number of displayed messages dependent on the available space?

Comment: Merely showing that the starred list space calculator isn't failing in all cases, @KevinVermeer.

Comment: @PopularDemand - How is it not failing in our screenshots?  Sure, it's not cutting anything off, but I had 950 pixels of whitespace, you had 200 in landscape and 650 in portrait.  That hardly seems like an accurate calculation of space.

Comment: I don't think the list is supposed to continue until _all_ the whitespace is filled. Isn't the decision to display based on number of stars vs. "hotness"? @KevinVermeer

Comment: That freaking click tease

Comment: *link tease* XD

Comment: https://github.com/HodofHod/SE-Modifications/blob/master/ChatMods.user.js

Comment: 1 easy fix for this is to add the style `overflow: auto` to `#sidebar`. Very curious why this is not fixed yet!

Comment: This still hasn't been fixed and the fix proposed or a userscript shouldn't be a solution. As alternative to those so that I only use things SE gives me I have to change the orientation of the display of my laptop to be able to clear stars because I cannot clear them from the stars page either. This cannot be it. You cannot say on one side that you encourage self-moderating chats and then don't support the access to features like that.

Comment: This CSS override will help out `#starred-posts { max-height: 300px; overflow-y:scroll; }` (tweak max-height for your screen)