# Is it appropriate to post an exact duplicate if the older question got no answer?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I posted [Chat "show x more" starred messages doesn't result in a scrollbar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298766/338259), which I'm aware is an exact duplicate of ["show X more" (starred) in chat is a tease](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117890/338259)

The older question is more than 5 years old and it's not going to get any new attention any time soon. If the newer question got an answer, we could mark the older question as a duplicate. Additionally, in this particular case it's a meta bug report, and the SE dev team may now have more time and resources to fix the bug; bringing it to their attention again may result in a bugfix.

At first I was quite sure that it should be fine, but thinking about it some more I'm not 100% sure. Is it appropriate and/or acceptable to post an exact duplicate of a question that has no answer? Does this differ between meta and non-meta?

Comment: @PolyGeo You people are too eager with your duplicates... that's not a dupe of this question. I'm talking about making a dupe of a question that has no answer; the linked question is talking about making a question that is closed as a dupe before it got any answers.

Comment: "and the second question had no answer at all"

Comment: @PolyGeo The second question being the _new_ question that was marked as a dupe, not the question of which it was marked a dupe. I feel like you didn't read this carefully enough :/

Comment: It's poorly written but I think I've read it right.  In any event there are acceptable ways to draw attention to unanswered questions - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287356/how-can-i-bump-other-users-unanswered-questions - and re-asking the same question is not one of them.

Comment: @PolyGeo I don't understand the way people vote on meta. So on meta.SE I _do_ get/lose rep from votes, yet people will downvote just because they think the answer to my question should be no? Unless they're downvoting because you (incorrectly) flagged as a dupe...? I would just delete my question but I want to leave it here because it's a good question. I'd just love to know what problem people have with the question.

Comment: People downvote (and upvote) for many reasons.  At the moment your question is at -4 and of the three guidelines offered for downvoting by its tooltip I would say that they are suggesting that it is "not useful".  At least two users agree that it is a duplicate, so that may be feeding into the downvotes. Your question has an upvoted answer so deleting it is not an option for you.

Comment: @PolyGeo I seem to be able to delete it.

Comment: You may be able to delete your other question (which has no answers) but I do not think that you will be able to delete this one while it has an upvoted answer.

Comment: @PolyGeo It warns me that repeated deleting of answered questions will get me question-banned, but I definitely seem to be able to delete it.

Comment: I note that you have not deleted this question so did you end up fully trying to?

Comment: @PolyGeo No I didn't. I want to leave it here because it may help other people in the future :)

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not fine at all.

If you want an old question to receive more attention, you should [place a bounty on it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/) or *even better*, edit the question to make more answerable, for example you can

- include better examples: link to an article, provide some code, make a diagram, write a hypothetical, whatever is appropriate to the particular Stack Exchange site.
- give it a title that is more balanced between brevity and detail: too vague and nobody cares, too much detail and people can't be bothered.
- fix the tagging: five years is a long time for tags to change, arise, decline or otherwise go in and out of favour.
- link relevant answered questions in a comment: this will grow a list of related questions that may help with answering. Be sure to only link truly relevant questions though.

Comment: Not convinced. Is a bounty appropriate for a bug report? What if you're a new user with too little rep? You'd have no choice but to ask a new question or just give up. Do you pretend that nothing has changed in 5 years and find a different site to ask on, or do you post a duplicate and hope that there are new people that might be able to answer your question (which, IMO, is the only valid solution in this situation). Regarding the other suggestions, in this specific case none of them are applicable. The original question can't be made any better.

Comment: Sure they are. There's at least one typo in that question.

Comment: @RobertLongson idk to whom you're responding and whether you're being sarcastic or not... :/

Comment: I'm not being sarcastic. I'm responding to you as the commenter on the question. Your statement that the question cannot be made any better is incorrect.

Comment: @RobertLongson Perhaps tag me in future, and quote which part you're responding to. I said a lot of things in that comment, I can't know what you're responding to. So you're saying I should suggest an edit for a single spelling mistake? Since when do they ever get approved?

Comment: You don't need to be tagged, you're the only commenter. To respond to your last comment, never if you don't try.

Comment: @RobertLongson Well _I didn't get notified_ so clearly that's not correct. Regarding editing to fix a single inconsequential spelling mistake, read [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit). It says `Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged`. Plus it seems just common sense that I shouldn't waste editor's time on silly little edits like that.

Comment: @Clonkex https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QG8Yr5tkyTg

Answer (score 1):

#### We have had cases where it is appropriate, but most of the time, it is not.

Please note that this is not my *opinion*; it is my direct observation of behaviour on one of our Stack Exchange sites.

---

In general, no. You probably should *not* create a deliberate duplicate, *even if the original has no answers*. As *Nij* points out, more elegantly, you have other ways to draw attention. Bounties are a good example.

*However*, there is at least one case where this *is* or *was* appropriate. Arqade ran a trial where *"but the answers there do not help"* was considered a perfectly legitimate reason to negate any duplication voting; ergo, the original not having *any* answer invited users to raise a duplicate question.

I am not sure how this went, or if the rule is still active on that specific Stack Exchange site, as it came up in alternate travels. I do not necessarily agree or disagree with this decision; it is simply not my call to make. It *does* act as an example of where (or *when*) this *might* have been acceptable, and I feel it appropriate to raise this case example, given the context. *When in doubt, always check Meta*.

Comment: I'm not a user of [gaming.se] but their Meta seemed to come down on the side of case by case close/re-open voting depending on eligible voter preference which makes it the same as every other site: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12426